# JavaScript runtime error: 'fidoCallback' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have built an asp.net application.  Every time I am running it, I am getting an error saying:

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in script block

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'fidoCallback' is undefined

I have tried adding

function fidoCallback(status) { }

but it is not helping.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The code started working fine when I copied the whole code to a new asp.net project.  Don't know what the issue was with the old one but now my project is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the actual reason behind the error.  It is because of the Nok Nok Labs installed.  Uninstall that from your extensions and then you can see that the error does not repeat.  No need to add fidocallback after this.

Comment: [from lenovo](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/FidoCallback-error-related-to-Nok-Nok-labs/td-p/1746805)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the name of the Nok Nok Labs package is "Multifactor Authentication Client". Just uninstall this package from "control panel/programs and features".